# How to use connection pooling with HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender

Tags: java, soap, connection-pooling, spring-ws

I am trying to make a Soap request using Spring WS. The request needs to send across client certificate to the server. I have figured out the configuration that makes the correct request to the server. Code presented below

```
@Bean
    public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender() throws Exception {
        HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
        httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.setTrustManagers(<TrustManager>);
        httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.setKeyManagers(<KeyManager>);
        httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        return httpsUrlConnectionMessageSender;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(<messageFactory>);
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(<jaxb2Marshaller>);
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(<jaxb2Marshaller>);
        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(<URL>);
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(());
        return webServiceTemplate;
    }
```

Now I was wondering how does HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender manage connections? Does it create new connection for every request or it has internal connection pooling. How do we use external connection pooling here?

Answer (score 3):

The client has default connection pool of 20 and default connection pool per request 2.

But you can overwrite it like this:

```
public HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender(Integer readTimeout, Integer connectionTimeOut,
            Integer throttlingLimit) {
    HttpComponentsMessageSender sender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();
    sender.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
    sender.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeOut);
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    CloseableHttpClient poolingHttpSoapClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connManager)
            .addInterceptorFirst(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor()).setMaxConnPerRoute(throttlingLimit)
            .setMaxConnTotal(throttlingLimit + 1).build();
    sender.setHttpClient(poolingHttpSoapClient);
    return sender;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need to send the client certificate for which I am forced to use HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender. This class does not have methods like setHttpClient. Whereas HttpComponentsMessageSender has setHttpClient but no support for setTrustManagers