# Spring boot concurrent api calls

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have REST api and client where i have GET, POST, PUT, DELETE queries. All of this works perfectly using Spring Boot, but i want to simulate multiple concurrent calls to REST api from client using Spring Boot.

Please, help me to do that.

Comment: What prevents you from just writing clients with curl, wget, postman, in Java, Perl, whatever else and run them against your API? You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using RestTemplate. If that's the case, you can simply use HttpClient with different configurations. For eg.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setMaxConnTotal(100)
    .setMaxConnPerRoute(50)
    .build();
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
```

Comment: Yes, I’m using it. And i also have a SOAP client, where i’m using WebServiceGatewaySupport, are there any solutions to do the same?

Comment: I'm not sure about SOAP client, but I guess this answer might help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54307212/3526708]

Comment: Thank you, i’ll try to do something

Answer (score 0):

you have some options:

- build a simple (test) Java client using [RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)
- use a tool like [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) where you can invoke URLs and simulate X concurrent requests
- use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), a CLI to perform HTTP request. It does not support concurrent requests but you can write a bash script to achieve something similar